# Alterar border-color conforme valor de uma variável jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tenho um formulário e quero alterar a cor do border-color para vermelho caso o usuário/email já tenha sido cadastrado no meu banco de dados.

Tentei algo como:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#btn_escrever').click(function(){
                if($(usuario_existe == 1){
                    $('#usuario').css({'border-color': '#A94442'});
                }

</script>
```

O btn_escrever é o botão onde utilizo para cadastrar;
o usuario_existe é uma variável que estou usando através do php para verificar se o usuário já existe ou não no bd, caso tenha valor 1, é porque já existe.
Algo está errado, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Altere $('#usuario').css({'border-color': '#A94442'}); por $( "#usuario" ).css( "border-color", "#A94442"); Referência: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: conseguiu solução para essa pergunta? fecha ela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem bastante coisa errada no seu código letícia.

bom vamos lá, primeiro o uso disso:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
```

pode ser substituído por isso:

```
$(function () {
```

Pois é a forma simplificada e nova do jQuery.

Depois você precisa alterar isso:

```
if($(usuario_existe == 1){
   $('#usuario').css({'border-color': '#A94442'});
}
```

pois claramente existe erros, eu fiz assim simulando sua variável do php com uma do javascript, mas é só você atribuir o valor:

```
usuario_existe = $('#usuario').val();

if(usuario_existe == 1){
   $('#usuario').css({'border-color': '#A94442'});
   alert('usuario_existe = 1'+usuario_existe);
}
```

fiz esse exemplo nesse [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1tn1wxc/1/)